# "no input file specified" with apache/php after recompile

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, fastcgi

I have CPanel and I recompiled php to 5.3.13 and im getting "no input file specified" on sites like vB and MyBB running in fcgi and suEXEC (same mode as before).

on build I have checked:
Mod SuPHP
Mod FCGID 
MPM Prefork

as far as i know when i did a recompile no options were changed. i had been running 5.3.8

any ideas as to what may be causing this? other sites work and running just fine.

```
php -v
PHP 5.3.13 (cli) (built: Jun  5 2012 08:56:58)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with eAccelerator v0.9.6.1, Copyright (c) 2004-2010 eAccelerator, by eAccelerator
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.0.12, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.33, Copyright (c) 2007-2012, by SektionEins GmbH

php-cgi -v
PHP 5.3.13 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jun  5 2012 08:59:06)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with eAccelerator v0.9.6.1, Copyright (c) 2004-2010 eAccelerator, by eAccelerator
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.0.12, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.33, Copyright (c) 2007-2012, by SektionEins GmbH
```

**cat /usr/local/apache/conf/php.conf**

```
# This file was automatically generated by the Cpanel PHP Configuration system
# If you wish to change the way PHP is being handled by Apache on your system,
# use the /usr/local/cpanel/bin/rebuild_phpconf script or the WHM interface.
#
# Manual edits of this file will be lost when Apache is updated.


# Fastcgi configuration for PHP5
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
MaxRequestsPerProcess 500
AddHandler fcgid-script .php5 .php4 .php .php3 .php2 .phtml
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php5
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php4
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php3
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .php2
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 .phtml

# End of autogenerated PHP configuration.
```

**cat /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5**

```
#!/bin/sh

# If you customize the contents of this wrapper script, place
# a copy at /var/cpanel/conf/apache/wrappers/php5
# so that it will be reinstalled when Apache is updated or the
# PHP handler configuration is changed

exec /usr/bin/php
```

**php -i**

```
'./configure'  '--disable-fileinfo' '--disable-pdo' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--enable-wddx' '--enable-zend-multibyte' '--enable-zip' '--prefix=/usr/local' '--with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs' '--with-bz2' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/lib' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/lib/php.ini.d' '--with-curl=/opt/curlssl/' '--with-curlwrappers' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-gettext' '--with-imap=/opt/php_with_imap_client/' '--with-imap-ssl=/usr' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libexpat-dir=/usr' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2' '--with-libxml-dir=/opt/xml2/' '--with-mcrypt=/opt/libmcrypt/' '--with-mm=/opt/mm/' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-openssl-dir=/usr' '--with-pcre-regex=/opt/pcre' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-pspell' '--with-snmp' '--with-tidy=/opt/tidy/' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--with-xsl=/opt/xslt/' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr'
```

**/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -l**

```
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_authn_file.c
  mod_authn_default.c
  mod_authz_host.c
  mod_authz_groupfile.c
  mod_authz_user.c
  mod_authz_default.c
  mod_auth_basic.c
  mod_file_cache.c
  mod_cache.c
  mod_disk_cache.c
  mod_mem_cache.c
  mod_include.c
  mod_filter.c
  mod_deflate.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  mod_env.c
  mod_mime_magic.c
  mod_expires.c
  mod_headers.c
  mod_unique_id.c
  mod_setenvif.c
  mod_version.c
  mod_proxy.c
  mod_proxy_connect.c
  mod_proxy_ftp.c
  mod_proxy_http.c
  mod_proxy_scgi.c
  mod_proxy_ajp.c
  mod_proxy_balancer.c
  mod_ssl.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_mime.c
  mod_status.c
  mod_autoindex.c
  mod_asis.c
  mod_info.c
  mod_suexec.c
  mod_cgi.c
  mod_vhost_alias.c
  mod_negotiation.c
  mod_dir.c
  mod_imagemap.c
  mod_actions.c
  mod_speling.c
  mod_userdir.c
  mod_alias.c
  mod_rewrite.c
  mod_so.c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed. Permission/User issues. CPanel glitched up with user names under httpd.conf #shrug

Comment: this is not a great answer, but it did help me to double check and yep.. also permissions problem :D in my case one php-fpm process with permissions of one user failing to read files in another user's directory